# How to use sz to transfer directory?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have 100G files in a root directory data/ on Server1 and I need to transfer from this remote machine to another remote machine Server2. SCP is disabled. I have to use "sz" command. This is the first time I use this command.

I need to first log onto Server2, and ssh to Server1, then issue the 'sz' command. 
What's the right format to use sz to transfer these files under data/ from Server2 to Server1?

**EDIT**:

```
    martin@parser:/data/reviews/ad$ ssh -p 80 user@xx.yy.com "tar -cz /data/ping/2017-10-05" > test.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/jumpserver/connect.py", line 877, in <module>
        main()
      File "/opt/jumpserver/connect.py", line 828, in main
    nav.try_connect()
  File "/opt/jumpserver/connect.py", line 614, in try_connect
    ssh_tty.connect()
  File "/opt/jumpserver/connect.py", line 459, in connect
    win_size = self.get_win_size()
  File "/opt/jumpserver/connect.py", line 320, in get_win_size
    x = fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), TIOCGWINSZ, s)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

SZ is not really the correct tool for the job.

The simplest way to do this is to not use sz at all, but to simply use SSH as a pipe.   There are lots of variants, but one way to do this would be to to compress the files into a data stream and write that stream to your local system.  This can all be done over SSH (leaving you a compressed backup is as follows:

```
ssh user@remote.server "tar -cz /data" > /path/to/local/filename.gz
```

If you want to take advantage of compression, but want the original file, you can do something like

```
ssh user@remote.server "tar -cz /data" | tar -xf
```

Which will compress the file into a stream, send it across the connection and decompress it.

Comment: ssh user@remote.server "tar -cz /data" | tar -xf. In this one, do I still specify the local path?

Comment: You don't need to - it will be relative to the current working directory.

Comment: Why have you thrown in "-p 80".  That connects it to port 80, which is almost always for web traffic.  (The default for ssh is port 22).  Do you actually have SSH access on server 2?

Comment: Yes, I do. I can connect with -p 80 on that server; otherwise, can't log in.

Comment: It seems like you are asking the wrong question.  When you connect to port 80, what do you get - ie are you connecting to a web page?  Why are you using SSH for this ?   Why do you think you have access to 100 gigs of data through this port ?